# UserAdmin save_model not triggering on password change

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to end the users session when ever the password is changed through the admin site (see screenshot). I did a research and it suggests to override the `save_model` and write the custom logic to end the session

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        print("HERE")
        ...
```

The problem is that for some reason `save_model` never triggers (tried debugging as well). Both User and UserAdmin are properly registered, otherwise I wouldn't even be able to access the Change Password page.

*Version: Django 4*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are right, because changing the password is a sensitive operation, apparently in the `UserAdmin`, they [defined special logic for this <sup>[src]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a702a0773dee8ea74119a8e0edf7ecc5d0ee4a1a/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L164-L167):

> ```
> @admin.register(User) class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     # …
>
>     @sensitive_post_parameters_m
>     def user_change_password(self, request, id, form_url=""):
>         # …
>         if request.method == 'POST':
>             form = self.change_password_form(user, request.POST)
>             if form.is_valid():
>                 form.save()
>                 # …
> ```

So in order to trigger the logic, you should *subclass* the `cange_password_form`, and override the `save()` method there, so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AdminPasswordChangeForm


class AdminPasswordChangeForm(AdminPasswordChangeForm):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('HERE')
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    change_password_form = AdminPasswordChangeForm
```